# Java - Scanner reads string with no assignment (Solved)

Tags: java, input

I am trying to have an input with only specific characters and spaces.
The problem is that the `Scanner` is reading a non assign string, forcing it to loop. **But it only happens/loops once.**

I have tried `input_nome = input.next()`.
However this way doesn´t let spaces to go on input.

```
public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int age = input.nextInt(); // This is the source of the problem!

System.out.print("Name: ");  
String input_nome;
while (true) {
    try {
        input_nome = input.nextLine();
        if (input_nome.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.err.print("Insert again: ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I expect this output "**Name:** "
But the actual output is this "**Name: Insert again:** "

---

### SOLUTION

This problem happens when `input.nextInt()` is used previously.
Just needed to use `input.nextLine()` in order to consume `\n` character. Like this:

```
...
System.out.print("Name: ");  
String input_nome;
input.nextLine(); // This clears the \n character
while (true) {
...
```

**Explanation:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056782/11860800

Comment: It works perfectly for me

Comment: @Goion the space is present in the []

Comment: @azro My bad. Yes it works completely fine.

Comment: I have separated the code, run it out, and it´s true it works. The problem is that that same piece of code is in a much larger java file and it doesn´t have the expected behavior. Is this a bug from netbeans?

Comment: Also, never let a catch block empty, at least use e.printStrackTrace()